# Filter import of rows from a zipped .txt file into google sheets based on text in one of the columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this Script to import a 10 column, 100k row zipped .txt file into google sheets. It works.

```
var url = "url goes here" 
var zipblob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob(); 
var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob); 
var unzipstr=unzipblob[0].getDataAsString();
var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(unzipstr);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
ss.getRange(1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
```

I would like to filter it so it only imports rows where the value in column 4 contains the string "2021" example values for this column are "Apr 24 2018 12:00 AM" and "2019-01-28 0:00:00" it switches between formats.

I have tried filtering by date hoping it would somehow work but that was fruitless.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check if it [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) `2021`:

```
var url = "url goes here" 
var zipblob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob(); 
var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob); 
var unzipstr=unzipblob[0].getDataAsString();
var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(unzipstr);
var f_csv = csv.filter(r=>r[3].includes("2021") || r[3].includes("-02-"));

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
ss.getRange(1, 1, f_csv.length, f_csv[0].length).setValues(f_csv);
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Let's say I wanted to filter what's coming through again, for cells that contain "Feb" or "-02-" 
How would I add that in?

Comment: check my answer. you can add as many `||` statements as you like

Comment: is there a way to write that as "-02-" or "Feb" so that it will catch both?

Comment: This is what it does yes

Comment: Let me clarify, I would like to filter for 2021, then in a new step filter just those results for -02- or Feb.

Comment: Then do what I did for two steps. Can you post a new question please ?@WARDEN

Comment: Right now I can post every 30 min. Will repost and comment link when I can.